# Select Distinct pair of column values

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, hiveql

I have a table like this

```
A1 | A2
a  | b
c  | d
b  | a
a  | b
```

And I want to select distinct pairs :

```
A1 | A2
a  | b
c  | d
```

I tried :

```
select a, b from (
select a, b , a|b as ab, b|a as ba from T
)t where ab!=ba group by a, b
```

Anyone have a better idea about how I can do this ?
Thanks

Comment: tag the DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Orcle, etc) which u r using.

Comment: There is no correlation between your data sample headers and your attempted query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ANSI compliant way of doing this would be to rearrange each pair of `A1` and `A2` values as min/max using `CASE` expressions.  Then just select distinct on this derived table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A1, A2
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN A1 < A2 THEN A1 ELSE A2 END AS A1,
        CASE WHEN A1 < A2 THEN A2 ELSE A1 END AS A2
    FROM yourTable
) t
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second `CASE` statement be `A2 < A1`, or just put it as an `ELSE`?

Comment: @Tony Yes, you could also write it that way, but then you'd also have to switch `A1` and `A2` in the predicate.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, sorry

Comment: Why not simply `SELECT DISTINCT CASE...`? (I.e. without a derived table.)

Answer (score 0):

This would be the cleanest way if NULL values are not involved

```
select  distinct
        least    (A1,A2) as A1
       ,greatest (A1,A2) as A2

from    t
;
```

---

```
+-----+-----+
| a1  | a2  |
+-----+-----+
| a   | b   |
| c   | d   |
+-----+-----+
```